# Spinner's shadow is cut off by invisible line rectangle

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Whenever I try to open my overflow spinner, the shadow appears up until a point at the bottom, where the shadow just simply dissapears.

[Please zoom at the spinner shadow, and notice there is a bottom line which stops the shadow from being further rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZ4a.jpg)

It might be hard to notice on a big screen, please zoom, however on a phone it is VERY noticeable.

There are no margin limitations. The shadow looks very ugly on phones.

Comment: Maybe try making shadow smaller, by lowering elevation value?

Comment: I wouldn't do this since it would break the material design rules and that way the shadow wouldn't be noticeable enough